# Large white space at bottom of page

Tags: php, html, css

There is a large white space left at the bottom of my page. I'm not sure how it got there or where it is coming from. I've looked through the index.php file and my various css files and I can't find anything or I'm overlooking something

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what it is and how to get rid of it.

Thanks!

The website is here: http://nova.wolfie-sims.com/index.php/main/index

Answer (score 2):

Remove `margin-bottom: 100%;` from `ul` element

```
{
  float: right;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  /* margin-bottom: 100%; */
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tambo. Available for a [chat?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/lets-get-shaped)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `margin-bottom: 100%` set on your `<ul>` that makes up your menu on the right-hand side. When I toggled it off, the excessive white space at the bottom sorted itself out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using margin in the ul element because of which margin is coming.

```
<ul style="width: 200px; padding-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 100%; margin-left: 40px; padding-top: 60px; float: right;" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
```

Remove the margin bottom from this code and everything should work wine. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

There is a margin-bottom: 100% being applied to the sidebar on the right. This is an inline style. You can see that in the markup.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="margin-bottom: 100%;">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
    ...
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Remove the inline style of margin-bottom: 100% from the sidebar markup (ul) as shown above. This will fix your issue.